# Replacing direct objects built with the partitive “du”/“de la” with pronouns

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, partitif

I have an assignment to replace direct objects with their pronouns, but I've been having trouble with one question.
How would you replace the direct object in:

> Est-ce que tu veux manger de la pizza ?
>
> Oui, je veux _____ manger.

Comment: French Language is not meant to do your homework. You could rephrase your question to make it fit the site. Please read the [Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Laure: Seems legit to me. The fact that it's homework doesn't change the fact that it's a perfectly valid question that can be answered and explained.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I fail to see the research effort in the question or has this part extract of the Help Centre become obsolete ? : "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. "

Comment: `I've been having trouble` means _I tried to without success_. Sometimes things are not clear and to explain what you tried is just as complicated as doing what you want. When this happens you can ask for help anyway. Some will help you and explain you how to solve your problems, and this explanation can help other people later. And some prefer to play the cop role, not helping anyone, and forgetting the rules they want others to respect, like _Be welcoming, assume good intentions_ in the _be nice_ section (won't talk about the third § title). Really, is that how you welcome a new member ?

Answer (score 1):

Oui je veux **en** manger. Because we talk of an undefined part of the pizza. If you'd put **la** manger, that would mean you'll eat it all.